# Laravel Auth::attempt() after executing, can't get properties of user

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

```
if (!$validation->fails() && Auth::attempt($input))
            {
                if (Auth::user()->role == ADMIN_ROLE)
                {
                    return Redirect::to('admin');
                }
                elseif (Auth::user()->role == USER_ROLE)
                {
                    return Redirect::back();
                }
            }
```

After the attempt() method executes, it returns TRUE, but after that I can't use the Auth::user() properties, I get an error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Why is that happening? can't figure it out...

also the Auth::login() method works fine

Comment: From a quick glance over the [auth code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php#L271) if `Auth::attempt()` works then you should be logged in, and should be able to use `Auth::user()` to get the user back again.  Are you certain that the error relates to the `Auth::user()` lines and not something within `Auth::user()`'s logic, or even the logic getting the role attribute?

Comment: i've dont changed any code inside Auth::user() it is as it was, the auth config is set correctly, the table is users and there is a column role - utf-8 varchar 255, if there was something wrong then the Auth::attempt() - should return false, but it returns true, so then I am missing something, but can't understand what it is

Comment: What is the stack trace for the error?  Where does it actually occur?  There are lots of places that "Trying to get property of non-object" could occur.  Additionally, are you using fluent or eloquent driver?

Comment: Ok, and the other questions?

Comment: That doesn't look like a Laravel 4 stack trace to me... The framework source for Laravel 4 is located in the `vendor/laravel` directory. (Have re-tagged)

Comment: That stack trace doesn't help with the actual line this is occurring on. Which of the lines in the code you've posted is line 20?

Comment: This is 4 years late but i sure do hope my response could help someone else. You are checking if validation is successful and user is successfully logged in. when these two conditions are true then you can use Auth::user(). if one of those conditions fails, you cannot get into that block of code. Best thing to do is to handle check for validation first implementing early exit then Auth::attempt

Answer (score 0):

If this was L5+, $this->validate is available in every controller within the controllers namespace. Once validation fails, error is sent to error bag and exits.

```
 $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);

// code to log user in
// a bunch of other code
```

If validation fails, errors are sent to the error bag and accessible anywhere.